# Why is logged value of promise confusing?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, google-chrome-devtools

Here is the code that I am using:

```
let myFirstPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(function(){
   // alert("sdf");
    resolve("Success!"); // Yay! Everything went well!
  }, 200);
});

console.log(myFirstPromise);
```

Why does the logged value display like this:
[image]

but then when I open it, it shows resolved?
[image]

Another case,
Lets say i change the 200 to 2000,
now

1. if i expand before 2 sec, it shows pending always, even if you expand again after 2 min.
2. if i expand after 2 sec, it shows resolved, and same there after.

Is there a reason it is so ?

Comment: Hover your mouse over blue "i"  icon.

Comment: Because it's not resolved when the `console.log` is executed, and then 200ms it **is** resolved. To see it logged only when resolved, use `myFirstPromise.then(console.log)`.

Comment: @torazaburo - that wont log the promise, that will log the resolved value of the promise :p

Comment: The reason your "another case" works as it does is because, well, that's how the console works.

Answer (score 1):

The first line you see is from the time you return the promise.

Its status is `pending` at that point (since it is not resolved) and it has no resolution value.

When you open it - the dev tools inspect the *live* promise - which means it shows the *current* status. Since you pressed it after more than 200ms - it is now fulfilled with the value "Success!".

Comment: Please have a look at the edited question